# From vertical to horizontal slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, sliders

I have this slider on my WP page, which is vertical. I would like to convert it so it his horizontal.  As I understood I need to change my JS code.

```
jQuery(function($) {
var image_es;
var zoom_timer;
var win_width = 0;

function resize_venedor_thumbs() {
if (win_width != $(window).width()) {
if (image_es) {
image_es.destroy();
}
image_es = $('#thumbnails-slider-756').elastislide({
orientation : 'vertical',
minItems: 4
});
win_width = $(window).width();
}
if (zoom_timer) clearTimeout(zoom_timer);
}
$(window).load(resize_venedor_thumbs);
$(window).resize(function() {
clearTimeout(zoom_timer);
zoom_timer = setTimeout(resize_venedor_thumbs, 400);
});
});
```

I tried to change vertical to horizontal in inspect element mode but it did not change at all.

Comment: Did you resize the window after you made the change?

Comment: Yeah it did not work. I just did that straight away in code editor and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

If you change the orientation to `'horizontal'` in inspect element mode, you need to make sure the `resize_venedor_thumbs` function is called.

It looks like it is called on load or resize (try resize because loading will erase your edits); or you can call it in the console yourself `resize_venedor_thumbs()`; or, of course, edit the source and load the page.